# Watch all elements of an object except one

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch in my code

```
scope.$watch(foo, function () {
   ...
}, true);
```

This ensures that if any attribute in the object foo changes then this watch will be called.  I want to make an exception to this.  I want to call this watch if any attribute in foo changes except one.  If that attribute changes this watch should not be called.  How is this possible?

Comment: Did you try making it conditional inside your watch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 different ways to do this:

Option 1, just handle it at the beginning of your `$watch` function:

```
scope.$watch(foo, function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if(newVal.propertyThatYouDontWantToWatch === oldVal.propertyThatYouDontWantToWatch)
        return;
   /* Normal Code here*/
}, true);
```

Option 2, define the property that you don't want to watch like this (I'm pretty sure that this option won't trigger the `$watch` of your `foo` object):

```
 Object.defineProperty(
                foo, 
                'propertyThatYouDontWantToWatch', 
                {
                    enumerable:false, 
                    configurable:true, 
                    writable: true, 
                    value:{} /*Replace {} with the value that you want to assign to your property*/
                 }
 );
```