# Angular deep compare objects except for specific properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, comparison, watch

Use case:

```
$scope.$watch('settings', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if (!angular.equals(oldVal, newVal)) {
       setDirty();
    }
}, true);
```

Now this is practically the same as

```
$scope.$watch('settings', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if (oldVal) {
       setDirty();
    }
}, true);
```

Since the `$watch` already compares the two.

However, there is one property that even though it changes i don't want to `setDirty()`.

This is my working (hacky) solution so far:

```
$scope.$watch('settings', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if (!oldVal) return;
   var editedOldVal = angular.copy(oldVal, {});
   var editedNewVal = angular.copy(newVal, {});
   delete editedOldVal.propertyIDontWannaWatch;
   delete editedNewVal.propertyIDontWannaWatch;
   if (!angular.equals(editedOldVal, editedNewVal)) {
       setDirty();
   }
}, true);
```

Is there a cleaner way to make `angular.equals()` or the `$watch` ignore specific properties?

EDIT:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144401/4341456) does not solve my problem since
 `option 1` is not a solution at all, says that if the property that i don't want to watch hasn't changed - do nothing, but this is exactly the property i want to ignore (don't care if it changed or not). 
`option 2` makes that property not comparable at all, i only want to ignore it on this specific case and not make it uncomparable by definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watch all elements of an object except one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144243/watch-all-elements-of-an-object-except-one)

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @lostintranslation Unfortunately no, ended up staying with the hacky solution, which is actually not that bad..

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix properties with a $ and it will not be included in the equals comparison. The angular.equals method ignores properties that start with a $. 


From the Angular.js code:

`if (key.charAt(0) === '$' || isFunction(o1[key])) continue;`

For example:

`var object1 = {propertyOne: '1', $myCustomHiddenField: 'something'};`

`var object2 = {propertyOne: '1', $myCustomHiddenField: 'something else'};`

`var result = angular.equals(object1, object2);//this is true`

The equals method can be referenced [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/258713a77db1a68527760832f185efe28008e3c2/src/Angular.js#L1058).

Comment: I was struggling with the same. This worked perfectly. Saved my day sir!